# What is correct way of implementing logout in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular, angular2-routing

I followed up the developer guide on "Routing and Navigation" topic where it describes **add the login component**. The implemented **logout** mechanism is poor and it does not update ui (at-least in my implementation it needs a refresh). As far as I see this issue, there have to be a redirection after this event.

I wonder what would be proper approach for implementing **log out redirection**?

1. Inside the authentication service?
2. Inside the component*?
3. With a separate route and component?
4. ...?

I am really confused in making the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

With a separate route and component is better option because once you logout you cannot route back.

```
when('/logout', {
template: '', //A logout template or templateUrl is required by AngularJS, even ifyour controller always redirects.
 controller: 'LogoutController'
}).
```